# copy a step from workflow in sharepoint designer 2010

Tags: workflow, sharepoint-designer

I'm using SharePoint 2010, I have created workflow.

1. I want to copy one step from the workflow and paste it to some other place inside the workflow.
2. I wnat to copy one step from the workflow and paste it to another workflow.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't, they need to be created from scratch.  Other workflow tools give you the option to save snippets and copy actions, but SharePoint Designer does not.

Answer (score 3):

You can edit the workflow.xoml and the workflow.xoml.rules files.

Perform These Steps:

> 1.) From SPD select Workflow and press "Export to Vsio"
>
> 2.) Goto Explorer and make a Backup copy of the exportet File (eg wf_name.vwi -> wf_name.vwi.bak)
>
> 3.) Rename the wf_name.vwi file to wf_name.vwi.zip
>
> 4.) Extract the Zip File
>
> 5.) You see the workflow.xoml and the workflow.xoml.rules file
>
> 6.) look at the seqence between the tag
>
> 7.) copy this Part to another Editor Window
>
> 8.) Replace all ID Nummber by new free numbers eg. ID3 -> ID503 (use capital Letter Option)
>
> 9.) paste the manipulated Part to into the original workflow.xoml where you want it to have.
>
> 10.) Do the same thing in the Rules file with this rules you have in the step. The tag is
>
> 11) Put the Files back to the ZIP and rename the ZIP back to vwi
>
> 12) Goto SPD and Press the "Import from VISIO Button.
>
> 13) If you got no error save and publish the Workflow
>
> 14) If you got errors search the error or import the original
>   Workflow.

HTH

Franz Frühwirth

Answer (score 2):

As PirateEric said you can't copy, but you can create you own workflow activity and use this activity in your workflow. see this link http://allthingssharepoint.wordpress.com/2011/02/21/custom-sharepoint-designer-activity/

Answer (score -2):

When I want to copy a step in SPD 2010, I just click on the step's box so it gets highlighted (blue), then ctrl+c, click where I want to paste it and ctrl+v.

Works both within the same workflow and from a workflow to another...

Comment: What??  You can't do this.  It is not possible.