# Sharepoint Designer 2013 because can not use copy & paste for an activity in workflow?

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I read this [question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/21906/copy-a-step-from-workflow-in-sharepoint-designer-2010), why can not I use copy & paste for an activity in workflow?

I used this function.

Could this be the cause of the error: 
"Errors were found when compiling the workflow. The workflow files were saved but cannot be run. Error-Unexpected error on server associating the workflow"

I followed the instructions on this [post](http://www.manjuke.com/2011/05/fixed-sharepoint-designer-error.html) but without result.

Answer (score 0):

The first link you provide answers your question.  Designer does not properly paste activities across workflows, and can cause errors.  Your options are to do what Franz's answer states, or to delete the activity pasted and create it manually.

Comment: thanks for the reply, but can not Micorsoft simply remove the feature instead of making it defective available? I lost days and days to find the cause of the problem .....

Comment: This is just one of many defects in the latest release of SharePoint.  Expect to find more.

Comment: as you expected I just found another one ....  http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/q/117690/33569