# Sharepoint Designer 2013 crashes when I publish a workflow with a approval process action

Tags: sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow

From a few days I can no longer publish with the SharePoint Designer old and new Workflows that contain a simple approval process Action, like this

```
->    Start Approval (7) process on Current Item with Alessandro Cosi
```

I am now receiving this error when attempting to publish:

> An error occurred while trying to fetch data from your Sharepoint site.

Comment: did you see any error in event log? any other information because this is very generic error.

Comment: check may be this solve the issue http://sriramkunapuli.com/2011/05/05/sharepoint-designer-error-an-error-occured-while-trying-to-fetch-data-from-your-sharepoint-site-unexpected-response-from-the-server-the-content-type-of-the-response-is-the-status-code-is-o/

Comment: I'm sorry I'm not very expert, you can tell me how can I Access the event log?

Comment: I checked, in the site web.config file the below entry was already present  <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled=”true” /> under <system.serviceModel>

Comment: try this link http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/open-event-viewer#1TC=windows-7  and open the event viewer and check all categories around the time it crashed...any other information / error you suspect which will help us to determine the root cause...

Comment: also check this one, http://community.office365.com/en-us/f/154/t/190807.aspx?pageindex=2

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the Problem ..... My Sharepoint Designer 2013 was 64 bit, I have installed the 32 bit Version and now can i publish my workflow!